# Access Linux variable into angular 6

Tags: angular, environment-variables

I know the method by setting it into *environment* file and access it in the `angular.json` file.

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
      "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
      "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

These values come from *environment* variables in Linux shell. Suppose I already have built UI code. I have to pass those values on run time whenever code runs in browser

My question is how to get dynamic value saved in machine's bash profile file, and use them in the code.

How to achieve it?

Comment: So you would like to read environment variables of a user that is browsing your angular application? Or is it some local application that will be always run on a single local environment?

Comment: Or do you want just those variables that are set on your build server?

Comment: i want those variables that are set in .bashrc file so that i can use them while developing application

Comment: So it is only for development? Because you definitely cannot read those data that belongs to other users when the app is deployed to internet.

Comment: yes it is only for development

Comment: And you need it just once when you build/serve the app, right?

Comment: yes,like I export a variable in .basrhc file which contain the base path of API of server side, I want to use that variable in my app